# how to allow user to format his aricales when user doesnot know html

Tags: user-interface, textarea, text-formatting

In my website i want to allow users to post aritcals.Users post articles in a  textarea as used by users of stackoverflow to post their question. Now i want to allow them to format articles, without having them to know html.User should be allowed to mark text as bold, put a image, mark some part as code,  etc (other things as used by stackoverflow and hubpages.com).

How can i provide shuch option in UI.
How do i support it DB?

Comment: How complex does it need to be? A complete WYSIWYG editor (eg stackoverflow answer box) or basic bb-code functionality (eg stackoverflow comment help)?

Comment: stackoverflow textbox which we use to post question is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an editor like TinyMCE ? 
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: Yes..it is.And perhaps the most used one.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openwebware.com/wysiwyg/demo.shtml

Try this one :)